# Delete whitespace after a character string (pointers)

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, whitespace

I have a struct list of names, last names, addresses... All inputted in separate CHAR strings.
The problem is whenever I paste one of these strings I also get a whole lot of whitespace afterwards.
For example, for Name and Last name strings, I get:
Britney............................................Johnson...................................
(dots represent space characters at the end of each string)

Here is my code:

```
void table_names (void)
{
ADDRESS *tmp_ptr;
printf ("All names in address book:\n");
tmp_ptr= hol; 
printf(" ______________________________\n");
printf("|  FIRST NAMES   | LAST NAMES  |\n");
printf("|________________|_____________|\n");
while(tmp_ptr!=NULL)
   {   
    printf ("%s%s",tmp_ptr->name,tmp_ptr->lname);
    tmp_ptr= tmp_ptr->next;
   }
}
```

Any help on how to get rid of the whitespace?

Comment: You haven't provided sufficient information. What does `ADDRESS` look like, and how are its contents being set?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by paste that you mean display.

With that assumption, I also assume that whenever tmp_ptr->name and tmp_ptr->lname are formed, their entire buffer is filled with spaces and only at the end is there a NUL terminator (`'\0'`).

Wherever those are created, you need to chop off all of the extra whitespace by putting a `'\0'` at the first sight of all blanks. Probably a smart approach would be to work backwards to allow for spaces in names.

```
int i;

for (i = BUFFER_LENGTH - 1; i > -1; --i)
{
    if (value[i] != ' ')
    {
        if (i + 1 != BUFFER_LENGTH)
        {
            value[i + 1] = '\0';
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This could be done with the raw pointer as well, and it assumes that this is passed in through a function similar to:

```
void rtrim(char *value, const int BUFFER_LENGTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

To print without trailing spaces, use format `.*s` and `strcspn()`.

`.*s` takes an `int` value as the maximum number of `char` to print.
`strcspn(s," ")` computes the length of the initial prefix not containing `' '`.

Modification of `s` is not needed.  This method does not work should a space occur *within* the last name.

```
int main(void) {
  const char *s = "Johnson        ";
  printf("'%.*s'\n", (int) strcspn(s, " "), s);
  return 0;
}
```

> 'Johnson'

Otherwise it is a bit more work.  Search for the last `' '`, if any.

```
int main(void) {
  const char *s = "Johnson Smith  ";
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  while (len > 0 && s[len-1] == ' ') {
    len--;
  }
  printf("'%.*s'\n", (int) len, s);
  return 0;
}
```

> 'Johnson Smith'